# Diffraction & Width of slit

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction, huygens-principle

I was told that diffraction through a slit occurs as follows-
When the 'point sources' of the planar wavefront at the location of the slit emit secondary wavelets we find bright and dark spots at unusual locations(which is according to Huygens' Principle).
Naturally, this effect will be greater when the wavefront is larger in size i.e. the slit is wider. But the fact is that diffraction occurs only in those slits whose width is of the order of the wavelength of light.
Have I understood it all wrong? Why does this happen?

Comment: Diffraction occurs regardless of the width of the slit.  It's just that it's easier to see the effects of diffraction when the slit width is comparable to the wavelength of light.

Comment: @S.McGrew Why so?

Comment: Please read about Huygens principle, which is a good way to start thinking about diffraction.  You will see that *any* change in a wavefront results in diffraction, but the pattern of diffraction depends on just what the change is.

Comment: Alright, will do that...thanks..!